# How can I use custom tags in my feeds to validate correctly?

Tags: xml, validation, rss

I have a feed with several custom tags that the validator at https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi keeps throwing errors at, like these:

```
Undefined item element: publication:type (882 occurrences)
        <publication_type>backgrounder</publication_type>
        ^
Undefined item element: pub:publisher (844 occurrences)
        <pub_publisher>andruxnet</pub_publisher>
        ^
Undefined item element: date:published (879 occurrences)
        <date_published>2014-02-26 00:00:00</date_published>
        ^
```

After googling around for a while I found that I need to [use a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302882/undefined-item-element-xml-rss) but I'm still unable to make this work, and the errors keep coming up.

So, I added the prefix in my header like this:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0">
```

I ommit the other xmlns attributes for brevity

Anyway, after making this modification, I got this:

```
XML parsing error: <unknown>:31:8: unbound prefix [help]
        <feedburner:publication_type>backgrounder</feedburner:publication_type>
        ^
```

I'm out of ideas here, I might need to create a completely custom namespace, but when I tried to, using `<rss version="2.0" xmlns:andrux="http://andrux.net">` and relacing my tags with the andrux: prefix I go back to the same errors as before, I don't know how to truly declare my custom namespace to make it work.